# Querying MongoDB from browser using a flask backend

Tags: mongodb, d3.js, flask

I am building an interactive visualization tool that lets users query a database which is then visualized using D3, Flask as the server and MongoDB as the database. My question: **How do I query the MongoDB (from Flask) with the user input and render this to the server?**

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you have done so far, what exactly is missing etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the mongodb and run its server (in terminal type mongo)
2. Install pymongo (python package)
3. Then create an instance of the pymong using:

> ```
> from pymongo import MongoClient
> client = MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
> db = getattr(client, DATABASE_NAME)
> ```
>
> 4. Then you can query using following:

```
> documents = db.your_collection.find()
> db.your_collection.insert({'name': 'Nabin Khadka'})
```

These python code can be wrapped in views.py file under a method. Like:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
   # All above code
   return jsonify(response_dictionary)
```

Then running the app, we can call the following url from browser:

```
https://url_to_server:port/test
```