# How to get data of collection in mongo db using python flask?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, flask

I am new to flask web frame work in python . i need to dump the data from collection in mongodb and save it into csv file by writing service in flask.and am getting collection data using following lines.

```
 wh_data.objects()
```

here wh_data is the name of the collection in mongodb.

Comment: please some help out with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288453/querying-mongodb-from-browser-using-flask-server/45294206#45294206